# Как в питоне заполнить нулями числа над диагональю в матрице

Tags: python

Как в питоне заполнить нулями числа над диагональю в матрице?

Answer (score 1):

Элемент находится на диагонали, если номер строки равен номеру столбца.

Соответственно если номер столбца больше номера строки, то элемент находится над диагональю.

```
a = [[1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if j > i:
            a[i][j] = 0

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Возможное усовершенствование - сразу задавать для j range  от i+1, тогда и проверять ничего не придётся